# Keep Windows 10 network port open on Logout .NET

Tags: .net, networking

Is there a way to keep an application's network port open when a user logs out? I have a project where I need to monitor a Windows 10 PC and it closes my connection upon logout.

Is this possible? Or will I need to create a separate service to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8fa70f65-7152-4cb0-af40-0e57046e4a63/how-to-keep-a-program-running-when-log-off?forum=w7itprogeneral).

> For this to happen the program needs to run as a service. Contact the
>   program designer and see if they have a version of the program that
>   runs as a service.